# Create a bluetooth connection Kivy

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, kivy

This is more of a basic OOP question than a Kivy one. I have an app with 4 buttons. When I press one, I want to initialize a bluetooth connection from my laptop to an arduino uno and also schedule a function that sends bluetooth info every second.

I'm using the following code:

```
class HomeScreen(Screen):
    def OnConnect(self):
        print('Start')
        port = "COM7"
        #connect to bluetooth
        bluetooth = serial.Serial(port, 9600)
        print("Connected to HC-06")
        bluetooth.flushInput()

        #schedule a function that sends tester present to arduino
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.SendData, 1)

    def SendData(self,*args):
        bluetooth.write(b"Boop")
```

Obviously "bluetooth" is not visible outside fct "OnConnect". I want bluetooth to be visible to both OnConnect & SendData but I only want to connect to the arudino when OnConnect is called. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That's not Arduino code.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at the documentation at:

https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html

It says:

> If you want to schedule a function to call with default arguments, you can use the functools.partial python module:

So I would think something like this should work:

```py
        #schedule a function that sends tester present to arduino
        Clock.schedule_interval(partial(self.SendData, bluetooth), 1)

    def SendData(self, bt):
        bt.write(b"Boop")
```